# Converting set of characters into numbers using list of replacement rules

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a text, as an example "aaaa" into a set of numbers as defined in a list of replacement rules, for example letterstonum . letterstonum takes in letters a to z and returns the respective number from 1 to 26.

it works fine when tried with individual letters for instance:

```
Replace[a, letterstonum]
```

1 was returned

What I want to do is the same for a set of characters, for instance aaaa or abjdfjs .

I tried the following:

```
ReplaceAll[Characters["aaaaa"], letterstonum]
```

but the only return I got was {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}

which is the same I get for evaluating`[Characters["aaaaa"]`

My desired output in this case, would be 11111 or {1,1,1,1,1}

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?

Any help would be much appreciated

here's letterstonum :

```
letterstonum = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, 
  g -> 7, h -> 8, i -> 9, j -> 10, k -> 11, l -> 12, m -> 13, n -> 14,
   o -> 15, p -> 16, q -> 17, r -> 18, s -> 19, t -> 20, u -> 21, 
  v -> 22, w -> 23, x -> 24, y -> 25, z -> 26}
```

Comment: It appears you have a local set of rules called `letterstonum` defined. Please post them.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking the string and making individual characters you can apply `LetterNumber` to each character. This can be done by `Map`.

```
Map[LetterNumber, Characters["aaaaa"]]
```

produces

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it works, what do I do if I want to get an output in the form of 11111

Comment: Is there a way to have the same effect as Map[LetterNumber, Characters["aaaaa"]] using my current set of rules(letterstonum) . I've added it to the post

Comment: Neat. Will be gd if it can  distinguish lower case & upper case characters

Answer (score 4):

When 1 is returned in the first case, it means you have replaced symbol a to 1 in your letterstonum. I guess your letterstonum is something like below

```
letterstonum = {a -> 1, b -> 2}
```

In the second case, the "a" is not symbol but character. Hence, if you want {1,1,1,1,1} in your second case, you need to replace character a to 1 like below

```
letterstonum = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And, yes, you're right, that is what my current letterstonum looked like, and changing it did the trick. Could you please tell me if there is anyway to do it with the initial one? and how can I get the output as 11111?

Comment: Ok there maybe better answers but here is quick fix.                                 letterstonum = {"a" -> "1", "b" -> "2"}
ReplaceAll[Characters["aaaaa"], letterstonum]
InputForm[%]
StringJoin[%]

Answer (score 4):

**With ToCharacterCode**

One can use the ASCII code of the letters properly shifted so as to start with `1` for `a`:

```
ltn[st_] := ToCharacterCode[st] - 96
```

For the string input `"aaaaa"`:

```
ltn["aaaaa"]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

**With letterstonum**

To use `letterstonum` *as posted* (i.e. with symbols rather than strings for the letters), a possible approach is

```
ltn2[s_] := ToExpression@Characters@ToString[s] /. letterstonum
```

This returns for the inputs `aaaaa` and `"aaaaa"`

```
ltn2[aaaaa]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)

ltn2["aaaaa"]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

To obtain an output of the form `11111`, you can consider instead

```
ltn2[s_] := FromDigits[ToExpression@Characters@ToString[s] /. letterstonum]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
letterstonum = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 6, 
   g -> 7, h -> 8, i -> 9, j -> 10, k -> 11, l -> 12, m -> 13, 
   n -> 14, o -> 15, p -> 16, q -> 17, r -> 18, s -> 19, t -> 20, 
   u -> 21, v -> 22, w -> 23, x -> 24, y -> 25, z -> 26};

FromDigits@("aaaaa" // Characters) /.
 (Replace[letterstonum, 
   x_Symbol :> ToString@x, 1])

(*  11111  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the original post, you have a list

```
letterstonum = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5, ... };
```

In that case, do

```
StringReplace["abracadabra", MapAt[ToString, letterstonum, {All, {1, 2}}]]
(* "1218131412181" *)
```

However, based on one of the OP's comments, it seems it is actually a list of rules that looks like this:

```
letterstonum = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5, ... };
```

In that case, these two options work:

```
StringReplace["abracadabra", ReplacePart[#, 2 -> ToString@Last@#] & /@ letterstonum]
StringReplace["abracadabra", MapAt[ToString, letterstonum, {All, 2}]]
```

Finally, I would just from the beginning define `letterstonum` as

```
letterstonum = {"a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> "3", "d" -> "4", "e" -> "5", ... };
```

and do

```
StringReplace["abracadabra", letterstonum]
```